# Como usar el web checkout de epayco en ionic

Tags: ionic

Necesito implementar epayco como pasarela de pagos en una aplicación que estoy desarrollando en Ionic, la documentación de epayco explica como usar el web-checkout en el siguiente link https://docs.epayco.com/docs/procesos-de-integracion, mas sin embargo cuando intento implementarlo en Ionic al compilarlo a móvil no funciona, me dijeron que usara el in-app browser pero no se como podría implementar la pasarela usando el in-app browser ya que por lo que veo solo sirve para abrir paginas webs desde la aplicación, como podría implementarlo?

Answer (score 0):

puedes hacer un api que haga la integraciòn con epayco, o con in-app browser te crear una pagina web que renderice el formulario de pago con los datos que le envies y lo abres allí...

eso sí si piensas publicarla en el app store obligado apple pay :/ y te toca ocultar esa funcionalidad.

Comment: tienes algun ejemplo o pagina donde pueda ver como enviarle los datos a la pagina web por in-app browser?